# Redirect every trailing folder to main folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

i have a couple of unwanted urls that i want to redirect:

```
/faq/
/faq/question/1-title
/faq/question/2-title
```

I want all the /faq/question/* urls to redirect to /faq, is that possible?

I have this but this doesnt work :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/faq/question/([^/]+)/?$ /faq
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples/attempts, please try following htaccess rules file. Make sure you are putting this new rule at top of your htaccess file(after https rules(to change http --> https rules) in case there are any present in your htaccess file).

Also make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Put your new rule here..
RewriteRule ^faq/question/ /faq? [R=301,L,NC]
###Make sure to keep rest of your urls here onwards...
```